# Python Interactive

Tags: python, terminal

Is there a way to execute a method automatically from a python file after each command input while in python interactive?

For example:
If I have a method that prints information about file, but I do not want to call that method constantly, how can I make it output after each command in python interactive?

Comment: Python's interactive interpreter is meant to be for simple testing. Check [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html) module. As far as I know there's nothing like what you asked. You can very easily wrap your code with testing logic in a module and then test your code interactively, so you don't have to call the function each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sys.displayhook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) is the function called to display values in the interactive interpreter. You can provide your own that performs other actions:

```
>>> 2+2
4
>>> original_display_hook = sys.displayhook
>>> def my_display_hook(value):
...     original_display_hook(value)
...     print("Hello there from the hook!")
...
>>> sys.displayhook = my_display_hook
>>> 2+2
4
Hello there from the hook!
>>>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!